# How to download all OpenStreetMap highways in a large area?

Tags: openstreetmap, download, overpass-api

I need to download all highways as line features from OpenStreetMap in a large area (about 10.000km²). Therefore I wanted to use **overpass-turbo** with the following statement in the wizard:

```
 highway=*
```

in my chosen bounding box.

Unfortunately it looks like my bounding box is too big, because I get the error:

```
 runtime error: Query run out of memory using about 2048 MB of RAM.
```

Do I have to change my overpass turbo query or is it not possible to download large datasets in overpass turbo? Which **alternative method** could I use to download all highways as line features in a larger region. I need to have all attributes, like the type of the highway, "foot=yes/no/...", "access="yes/no/....", etc. and if I use something like geofabrik, these attributes do not appear.

Comment: Can you post your query as overpass turbo shortlink ("Share" button)?

Comment: > I use something like geofabrik, these attributes do not appear.


Are you using shape files? Try .pbf format instead.

Comment: thank you very much. The link to my overpass turbo query: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hC3

Would you say my extent is too large?

If i enter a maxsize, I get the following message: "Request rejected. (e.g. server not found, request blocked by browser addon, request redirected, internal server errors, etc.)

Error while parsing the data (parsererror)."

see: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hC4

Comment: I would highly recommend to use a download manager like wget rather than trying to download via browser. Use the link provided via "Export" -> "raw data directly from Overpass API" in overpass turbo for that purpose. In addition, change your parameter settings to something like `[timeout:3600][maxsize:2073741824];`. The resulting file will be about 1.3GB in size.

Comment: thank you for your valuable help. So the download with these settings (http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/hCr) worked for you using wget? Therefore you did not execute the query in overpass turbo, you just went to "Export" -> "raw data directly from Overpass API" an right-clicked and copied the URL (did not left-click it)? Since I have no clue about wget, could I use this tutorial for wget? https://builtvisible.com/download-your-website-with-wget/   Would WinWGet be an appropriate tool?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with wget on Windows. My point was to download the data in a way that it's not shown in a browser window but downloaded to a file instead. 1.3GB will for sure kill the browser when trying to display the data. If you're unsure how this all works, you should probably start with a very small bounding box and increase the size as you're getting more comfortable with the overall process.

Answer (score 3):

You can kill any web API with too large requests.

As an alternative, download an extract of Geofabrik that fits your study area, and run the query using osmosis or osmfilter.

Comment: 2048 MB is just the default setting if you don't provide a `[maxsize: ]` parameter setting. That's far from killing the web API.